# get AM / PM from users set time on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am wondering if there is a way that you can get am/pm from the users set time on iOS.

I am currently using this method to get time:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
hours.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"m"];
minutes.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
if ([minutes.text intValue] < 10) {
    minutes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
}
[formatter release];
```

I know I am using HH to get the hours and for the 12 hour format I have to use "hh" bu this does not solve the problem, I need to retrieve the AM/PM.

Hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you go. This is the date with am/pm formatting.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"Today's Date and Time: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: Yessir. a is the am/pm indicator.

Comment: can we make am/pm in capital? like "17-07-2014 12:25AM" is more appropriate then "17-07-2014 12:25 am" ...

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer with Swift:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "a"
let currentAMPMFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()).uppercaseString
```